# Discrete spectrum under a finite rank perturbation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space. Assume the discrete spectrum of $A$ is empty. Let $B$ be a finite rank operator.

I have learned that the essential spectrum of $A+B$ and $A$ are the same, but what can be say about the discrete spectrum of $A+B$?

If we further assume $B$ is self-adjoint so it has $k =$ rank($B$) eigenvalues, then can we say that $A+B$ has at most $k$ eigenvalues?